# Generating a dump file from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to generate a mysql dump file from PHP using the following:

```
exec('mysqldump -u root -ppassword maindb > c:\DB_Dump.sql');
```

However the file being generated is blank. Anyone knows what's wrong?

From the cmd, this is working:
`cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin`  to change the path and then

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword maindb > c:\DB_Dump.sql
```

But I'm trying to do it within PHP.

Comment: is mysqldump in your path? Try adding an absolute path to the command. `exec('/usr/bin/mysqldump ....')` and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried this   exec('C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqldump -u root -proot bespoke > c:\\DB_Dump.sql');   but still the same thing

Comment: the root dir is usually not writable by ordinary users.

Comment: But I'm not executing this as a user. It's just one line of code which is above

Comment: Did you try to redirect stderr to see if there are any errors?
`exec('... > c:\DB_Dump.sql 2> c:\file.err.txt')`

Comment: All programs, including PHP scripts invoked via a webserver, run under SOME user's ID. Whether it's IUSR_INET or your own windows login, those are ordinary user accounts and are not likely to have write permissions on C:\, unless you're still on Windows NT.

Comment: after printing out the error I got the following   exec('mysqldump -u root -ppassword maindb > c:\DB_Dump.sql 2> c:\file.err.txt'); ---> 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.   for exec('C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqldump -u root -ppassword maindb > c:\\DB_Dump.sql 2> c:\file.err.txt');  ---> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: No not window NT. I'm running on XP. I just tried it on window 7 and still same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To discard most common issues:

- Use full paths
- Send output to a publicly writable directory

The path to mysqldump in your computer appears to have white spaces. Make sure you quote it properly:

```
exec('"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\bin\\mysqldump" -u root -ppassword maindb > c:\\DB_Dump.sql 2> c:\file.err.txt')
```